# .htaccess in iframe in a Webview

Tags: android, .htaccess, iframe, webview

I have a webview app that I've created that pulls in a password protected camera feed with a .htaccess file protecting it.  Of course, it says that it's unauthorised.

I found this bit of code:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
                                          HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {

        handler.proceed("user", "password");

    }
}
```

I'm assuming this would work if the whole page was protected but it doesn't seem to work where it's the iframe that's protected.

Is there another way I can do this?